# How can my regex for finding multiple spaces not match newlines?

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I run this regex on #q keyup event to avoid extra spaces in a string.

```
$('#q').val($('#q').val().replace(/\s+/g,' '));
```

The problem is that it is also deleting all new lines. How can I delete extra spaces but keep new lines intact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that `\s` represents *all* whitespace including newlines. If you just want spaces, you can have a literal space:

```
$('#q').val($('#q').val().replace(/ +/g,' '));
```

If you want spaces and tabs, you could use a character class instead:

```
$('#q').val($('#q').val().replace(/[\t ]+/g,' '));
```

Answer (score 1):

Looking for `\x20+` [does the trick](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/eSE9Y/):

```
$('#q').val($('#q').val().replace(/\x20+/g,' '));
```

20 is the Hex code for the space character. You were looking for all whitespace characters, including newlines.